# Exception occured when Oracle ADF web application running on Glasfish v3.1

Tags: java, oracle, glassfish-3, oracle-adf

Using Jdeveloper 11.1.2.4 jdk1.6.0_39 with JSF2.0.
Want my web application to run on glassfish v3.x. Followed that url regarding this https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/deploying_oracle_adf_applications_to
I could deploy my ear successfully, and page renders as well.
But when triggered mbean method by clicking component on my jspx page, faced below exception. 
What might be the reason?
thx in advance.

Here are the domain/lib jars:

```
adf-controller-security.jar
adf-essentials.zip
adf-share-base.jar
adf-share-ca.jar
adf-share-security.jar
adf-share-support.jar
adflogginghandler.jar
adfsharembean.jar
commons-el.jar
dms.jar
javamodel-rt.jar
javatools-nodeps.jar
jrf-api.jar
jsp-el-api.jar
list.txt
mdsrt.jar
oc4j-ws-support.jar
ojdbc6dms.jar
ojdl.jar
ojdl2.jar
oracle-el.jar
oracle.classloader_11.1.1.jar
oracle.http_client_11.1.1.jar
oracle.logging-utils_11.1.1.jar
oracle.web-common_11.1.1.jar
oracle.xdb_11.1.0.jar
orai18n-mapping.jar
org.apache.bcel_5.1.jar
org.apache.commons.beanutils_1.8.3.jar
org.apache.commons.logging_1.1.1.jar
resourcebundle.jar
share.jar
xmlef.jar
xmlparserv2_sans_jaxp_services.jar

(3);|ADF_FACES-60098:Faces lifecycle receives unhandled exceptions in phase PROC
ESS_VALIDATIONS 3
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/secur
ity/idm/IMException
...
|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.Registration
Configurator|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-9999(3);| 
ADF_FACES-60096:Server Exception during PPR, #1 javax.servlet.ServletException:
 oracle/security/idm/IMException at 
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:521) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to a jar conflict or maybe some jars are missing. Maybe you are using some other jars (in your application) apart of the ones you have included within your glassfish. Try to run a simple Fusion Web App (ex: only one jsf in it) and see if it runs. If it doesn't work then you might consider trying another Glassfish or to reconfigure it. I am using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 without problems.